# I'm getting an NaN error whenever I run this?

Tags: javascript, html

I heard that NaN errors are when you are trying to pass an object as a number, yet in my HTML, 'productquantity' is set as a number, so why is it giving me this error? These files operate with another HTML file and another JavaScript file to retrieve data and these 2 display the data. 'productquantity is what is my only hurdle and where the NaN error comes up. If you need the other HTML and Javascript file, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

```js
"use strict";

function getBooking() {
    var laptopsprice = 0;
    if (sessionStorage.fname != undefined) {    //if sessionStorage for username is not empty
        //confirmation text
        //outputs user details in payment page and stores values to be sent to server in hidden input tags
        document.getElementById("confirm_name").textContent = sessionStorage.fname + " " + sessionStorage.lname;
        document.getElementById("confirm_email").textContent = sessionStorage.email;
        document.getElementById("confirm_phone").textContent = sessionStorage.phone;
        document.getElementById("confirm_streetname").textContent = sessionStorage.streetname;
        document.getElementById("confirm_suburb").textContent = sessionStorage.suburb;
        document.getElementById("confirm_state").textContent = sessionStorage.state;
        document.getElementById("confirm_postcode").textContent = sessionStorage.postcode;
        document.getElementById("confirm_laptops").textContent = sessionStorage.laptops;
        document.getElementById("confirm_productquantity").textContent = Number(sessionStorage.productquantity);
        document.getElementById("confirm_cost").textContent = laptopsprice;
        laptopsprice = totalproductcost(sessionStorage.laptops, Number(sessionStorage.productquantity));
        
        
        //values for hidden input tags that send data to the server
        document.getElementById("a_name").value = sessionStorage.fname + " " + sessionStorage.lname;
        document.getElementById("a_email").value = sessionStorage.email;
        document.getElementById("a_phone").value = sessionStorage.phone;
        document.getElementById("a_streetname").value = sessionStorage.streetname;
        document.getElementById("a_suburb").value = sessionStorage.suburb;
        document.getElementById("a_state").value = sessionStorage.state;
        document.getElementById("a_postcode").value = sessionStorage.postcode;
        document.getElementById("a_laptops").textContent = sessionStorage.laptops;
        document.getElementById("a_productquantity").textContent = Number(sessionStorage.productquantity);
        document.getElementById("a_cost").value = laptopsprice;
    }
 }


function totalproductcost(laptops , productquantity) {
    var laptopsprice;
    if (laptops == "Workstation_Laptop") {
        laptopsprice = (productquantity * 2499);
    } else if (laptops == "Gaming_Laptop") {
        laptopsprice = (productquantity * 1789);
    } else if (laptops == "Laptop_Stand") {
        laptopsprice = (productquantity * 64);
    } else if (laptops == "Office_Laptop") {
        laptopsprice = (productquantity * 1499);
    }  
    return laptopsprice;
}



 function cancelBooking(){
    window.location = "enquiries.html";
    sessionStorage.clear();
}
//function for invoking getbooking and validate, cancel booking
function init() {
    document.getElementById("paymentform").onsubmit = validate;
    document.getElementById("cancelpurchase").addEventListener("click", cancelBooking);
    getBooking();//invokes getbooking function
}
//invokes init fuction on window load
window.onload = init;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="scripts/payment.js"></script>
    <title>SwinTech</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"> </head>


    <header class="enquiriespage">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="logo"> <img src="logo.png" alt="logo"> </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="enquiries.html">Enquiries</a></li>
                <li class="active">><a href="payment.html">Payment</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>

<section class="paymentthing">
    <div class="paymentcontainer">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Order Summary:</legend>
            <p>Your Name: <span id="confirm_name"></span></p>
            <p>Your Email: <span id="confirm_email"></span></p>
            <p>Your Phone Number: <span id="confirm_phone"></span></p>
            <p>Street name: <span id="confirm_streetname"></span></p>
            <p>Suburb: <span id="confirm_suburb"></span></p>
            <p>State: <span id="confirm_state"></span></p>
            <p>Postcode: <span id="confirm_postcode"></span></p>
            <p>Product: <span id="confirm_laptops"></span></p>
            <p>Product Quantity: <span id="confirm_productquantity"></span></p>
            <p>Total Cost: $<span id="confirm_cost"></span></p>
            <input type="hidden" name="name" id="a_name" />
            <input type="hidden" name="email" id="a_email" />
            <input type="hidden" name="phone" id="a_phone" />
            <input type="hidden" name="streetname" id="a_streetname" />
            <input type="hidden" name="suburb" id="a_suburb" />
            <input type="hidden" name="state" id="a_state" />
            <input type="hidden" name="cost" id="a_cost" /> 
            <input type="hidden" name="laptops" id="a_laptops" />
            <input type="hidden" name="postcode" id="a_postcode" /> 
            <input type="hidden" name="productquantity" id="a_productquantity" />

        </fieldset>
        <br>
        <br>
        <form id="paymentform" method="post" action="https://mercury.swin.edu.au/it000000/formtest.php">
            <label for="cardType">Please Choose a Card Type:</label>
            <br>
            <br>
            <select name="cardType" id="cardType" required="required">
                <option value="">Please Select</option>
                <option value="Visa">Visa</option>
                <option value="Mastercard">Mastercard</option>
                <option value="American Express">AmEx</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="cardName" id="cardName">Please Enter Name On Card:</label>
            <input type="text" name="cardName" maxlength="40" required="required">
            <br>
            <br>
            <label>Please Enter Credit Card Expiration Date:</label> <span class="expiration">
    <input type="tel" name="month" placeholder="MM" maxlength="2" size="2" required="required" />
    <span>/</span>
            <input type="tel" name="year" placeholder="YY" maxlength="2" size="2" required="required" /> </span>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="cardNo">Credit Card Number:</label>
            <input id="cardNo" type="tel" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9\s]{13,19}" autocomplete="cc-number" maxlength="16" placeholder="xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx" required="required">
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Check Out">
            <br>
            <br>
            <button type="button" id="cancelpurchase">Cancel Purchase</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
<div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-content"></div>
    <div class="footer-bottom"></div> &copy; swintech.com | Designed by Bilal El-leissy </div>

</html>
```

Comment: When I run your code, there seems to be no problem

Comment: That's because you are missing the other HTML and JavaScript file where you input the values and store it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anytime you retrieve or set a value to go in a html tag or form element it is a string. Even if you cast that item as a `Number()`, the DOM will store it as a string. Whenever that string is to be used in a calculation, convert it to a number then with the plus operator, parseInt or parseFloat, as in:

```
function totalproductcost(laptops , productquantity) {
    productquantity = +productquantity;
    // OR productquantity = parseInt(productquantity);
    // OR productquantity = parseFloat(productquantity); if you have a decimal to consider

    var laptopsprice;
    if (laptops == "Workstation_Laptop") {
        laptopsprice = (productquantity * 2499);
    } else if (laptops == "Gaming_Laptop") {
        laptopsprice = (productquantity * 1789);
    } else if (laptops == "Laptop_Stand") {
        laptopsprice = (productquantity * 64);
    } else if (laptops == "Office_Laptop") {
        laptopsprice = (productquantity * 1499);
    }  
    return laptopsprice;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @PerfectFry - feel free to mark this as the answer if it solved your issue. Thanks

Comment: Wait, so I'd need to do the same thing in the getBooking function? For example should it be changed to document.getElementById("confirm_productquantity").textContent = Number(sessionStorage.+productquantity);    Basically putting a + after sessionStorage.

Comment: It's really not all that hard to understand. To make calculations, you need Numbers. As soon as you read from or put in the DOM, you need Strings. Assigning Numbers to e.g. `textContent`, or trying to store numbers in sessionStorage automatically converts it to a string.

Comment: No. Only concern yourself with number casting when you're doing calculations. `textContent = Number(sessionStorage.+productquantity)` is an error, and even without the erroneous + it isn't necessary - because it's getting stored as a string in `element.textContent` - so this can simply become `document.getElementById("confirm_productquantity").textContent = sessionStorage.productquantity;`

Comment: function totalproductcost(laptops , productquantity) {
 var laptopsprice;
 if (laptops == "Workstation_Laptop") {
  laptopsprice = parseInt(productquantity * 2499);
 } else if (laptops == "Gaming_Laptop") {
  laptopsprice = parseInt(productquantity * 1789);
 } else if (laptops == "Laptop_Stand") {
  laptopsprice = parseInt(productquantity * 64);
 } else if (laptops == "Office_Laptop") {
  laptopsprice = parseInt(productquantity * 1499);
 }  
 return laptopsprice;
}


sorry if it's hard to read but I put ParseInt behind every productquantity in the calculation. Still NaN.

Comment: No. convert `productquantity` at the top of your function like in my answer, then leave everything else the same. `laptopsprice = parseInt(productquantity * 2499);` should become `laptopsprice = parseInt(productquantity) * 2499;` but there's no need to do this every line. Just convert the variable to a number at the beginning

Comment: function totalproductcost(laptops , productquantity) {
 productquantity = +productquantity
 var laptopsprice;
 if (laptops == "Workstation_Laptop") {
  laptopsprice = parseInt(productquantity * 2499);
 } else if (laptops == "Gaming_Laptop") {
  laptopsprice = parseInt(productquantity * 1789);
 } else if (laptops == "Laptop_Stand") {
  laptopsprice = parseInt(productquantity * 64);
 } else if (laptops == "Office_Laptop") {
  laptopsprice = parseInt(productquantity * 1499);
 }  
 return laptopsprice;
}

It still gives me NaN :(

Comment: @PerfectFry - Look at the function you pasted in there and the function I have in my answer. They're not the same. The one you pasted has errors, which I point out in my comment directly above it. When you use the function I put in my answer, do you still get NaN?

Comment: @JohnTyner Yes, I directly copied and pasted your answer into my code and it didn't work sadly.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you might want to check for.

One is that productquantity has a value. If it's undefined or null, Number will return NaN.

The other is that if productquantity is being set as a string, that the string doesn't contain non-numerical characters.

Comment: *If it's undefined **or null, Number will return NaN**.* `Number(null)` returns `0`, not `NaN`. Same is true for the empty string.

Comment: productquantity is a number. What should I change to facilitate that? Thanks for your answer by the way.

Comment: Whoops, that was my misreading, I was seeing the Number being called in the initial setting of the fields. You can still use Number to pass either a string as a number ("1234", "1234.99") or use parseInt, parseFloat as John Tyner pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Adding ".value" to the input helped me